# Greens reciprocity theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

The [Greens reciprocity theorem](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=Greens+reciprocity+theorem) is usually proved by using the [Greens second identity](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=Greens+second+identity). Why don't we prove it in the following "direct" way, which sounds more intuitive:

$$\int_{\text{all space}}\rho(\mathbf{r})\Phi'(\mathbf{r})dV=\int_{\text{all space}}\rho(\mathbf{r})\left(\int_{\text{all space}}\frac{\rho'(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}dV'\right)dV$$
$$=\int_{\text{all space}}\rho'(\mathbf{r'})\left(\int_{\text{all space}}\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r})}{|\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r}|}dV\right)dV'$$
$$=\int_{\text{all space}}\rho'(\mathbf{r'})\Phi(\mathbf{r'})dV'$$

Is there any problem of the above proof?

Comment: An even faster way is to note that $\langle\rho_1,\Phi_2\rangle=\langle\rho_1,\nabla^{-2}\rho_2\rangle=\langle \rho_2 ,\Phi_1\rangle$ since $\nabla^{2k}$ is Hermitian for integer $k$.

Comment: The classical 1906 textbook "The mathematical theory of electricity and magnetism" by James Jeans (of "Rayleigh-Jeans law" fame) uses the [same trick](https://archive.org/stream/mathematicalthe02jeangoog#page/n108/mode/2up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is OK with your proof, at last when the two densities of charge are (measurable) bounded functions with bounded support, as physically expected. In that case all the manipulations of integrals you did are allowed by Fubini and Tonelli's theorem.